Tax on incentivized reviews with full refunds?
I purchase an item from a seller on amazon. I leave a review, and the seller sends me via paypal the full cost of the item plus paypal fees (a "refund" but I keep the item), say a total of $30.
Am I now liable for taxes for the $30? Would the cost of purchasing the item be deductible as an expense? How would I even report/categorize this type of income?

This is an international site and tax laws vary around the world. Please edit or comment to say where you are.

Did you have to leave a 5-start review? I'm pretty sure Amazon doesn't like paid 5-start reviews...

Note that there's now an FTC regulation banning this


Am I now liable for taxes for the $30? Would the cost of purchasing the item be deductible as an expense? How would I even report/categorize this type of income?

This is earned income. You're provided a review and got the free product for doing so. The value of the product (i.e.: the refunded $30) is your income.
